# Three 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

hope some could help me.

I have a wordpress blog with 3 domains, .com, .es and .net. The .com is the target.

And i want to redirect from non-www to www as well.

The redirect from .es to .com works fine, and .net to .com too. But when i add the redirect from non-www to www is not working and the site doesnt load.

This is my .htaccess file...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myblog.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myblog.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myblog.es$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myblog.es$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.myblog\.com/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myblog\.es$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.myblog\.es$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/myblog\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myblog.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myblog.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myblog.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: If you have the network tab open in Firefox/Chrome, what redirects do you see occuring?

Comment: When i type myblog.com and expected to be redirected to www.myblog.com on the network tab shows Method GET, Domain myblog.com and next row www.myblog.com but just keeps doing it and the site doesnt load.

Comment: You have two different RewriteCond matching `myblog.es, www.myblog.es` but with different outcomes. (the first redirects to `www.myblog.com`, the other to `myblog.com`, which will then be redirected to `www.myblog.com`. Please edit above to include exact input and output URL examples. Where the browser starts, and where it should be redirected in each case.

Comment: Network tab,shows that www.myblog.com was 301 Moved Permantly. But how? Thats the target url.

Answer (score 0):

These rules should suffice for your needs:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# redirect myblog.es and myblog.net (with or without www.) to www.myblog.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myblog\.(es|net)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force www on myblog.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myblog.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myblog.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```